# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in npm run command

Tags: npm

I'm working on Laravel project where using node version: v8.12.0 and npm version: 6.4.1. When I ran `npm run watch` command, I get error referenced to attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ohh after a hard job finally got the solution: Just deleted : public/mix-manifest.json And then run : npm run watch It is working fine for me.